# Which addon adds a search bar and buttons to the UI below the 3D view header?

Tags: interface

In this video https://youtu.be/mM3M1Vj6DxQ?t=31 , there is a non-standard panel layout (Blender 2.93):
[image: example video]

How to set up or get it?

Thank you

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: If you mean the section in the centre of the screen on the same line as the object menus, it's for the Blenderkit addon which you can get [here](https://www.blenderkit.com/get-blenderkit/).

Comment: Thank you. He has Tool Settings at the top, and the menu at the bottom, under Tool Settings

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean now. That standard layout changed between version 2.93 and 3.0 and above and I don't think there's any option to change it.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: No problem. I still have all Blender LTS versions back to 2.83 installed here so it's easy to compare them.